# How do you Connect ATALA to Plutus Smart Contracts

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, on-chain, smart-contract, atala-prism

I think they use diffrent programming languages, but how can I use DID inside my Plutus contracts?

Comment: I do not have the answer for you but you are welcome to join the Atala PRISM Pioneer Program to find out how this can be done! https://atalaprism.io/app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current state of the two projects it is impossible to do so on the Plutus mainnet. The problem here is not that they use different languages (although that does make things a little trickier) its the fact that ATALA requires custom infrastructure (nodes) that do not currently exist in Plutus.